# Minutes not showing on count-up timer

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I'm working with the following script for a count-up timer. It has no problem counting up in seconds but I'm having trouble getting it to display minutes. For example 1:35 (one minute and 35 seconds)
Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
var clicked = false;
var sec = 00;
var min = 00;

function startClock() {
  if (clicked === false) {
    clock = setInterval("stopWatch()", 1000);
    clicked = true;
  } else if (clicked === true) {}
}

function stopWatch() {
  sec++;
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = sec;
}

function stopClock() {
  window.clearInterval(clock);
  sec = 0;
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = 0;
  clicked = false;
}

var min = 0;
var second = 00;
var zeroPlaceholder = 0;
var counterId = setInterval(function() {
  countUp();
}, 1000);

function countUp() {
  second++;
  if (second == 59) {
    second = 00;
    min = min + 1;
  }
  if (second == 10) {
    zeroPlaceholder = '';
  } else
  if (second == 00) {
    zeroPlaceholder = 0;
  }

  document.getElementById("count-up").innerText = min + ':' + zeroPlaceholder + second;
}
```

```html
<div class="timer">
  <div id="timer">0:00</div>
  
  <input type="button" id="btnParentButton" value="start timer"  onClick="startClock()"/>
```

Comment: Leading zeros are not included in numbers, you need strings to represent numbers with leading zeros. A popular trick to add a leading zero if needed: `var minStr = ('0' + min).substr(-2);`.

Comment: Why do you have two variables `sec` and `second`? You are also `var`ing`min` twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this can help you.

The better way is to have your minutes and secs as global variable and simple function for each button

**EDIT**

Update code using pure JS

```js
var min = 0;
var sec = 0;
var timer = undefined;
var isStarted = false;

function startcount(){
  sec++;
  if(sec==60)
  {
    sec=0;
    min++;
  }
  updateClock();
}

function updateClock(){
  var displaySec = sec < 10 ? "0" + sec : sec;
  var displayMin = min < 10 ? "0" + min : min;
  document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = displayMin + " : " + displaySec;
}

function start(){
  if(timer == undefined || !isStarted){
    timer = setInterval(function(){
    startcount();
    },1000);
  }
  isStarted = true;
}

function stop(){
  isStarted = false;
  clearInterval(timer);
}

function reset(){
  stop();
  min=sec=0;
  timer = undefined;
  updateClock();
}


updateClock();
```

```html
<div id="count"></div>
<button class="start" onClick="start()">Start</button>
<button class="stop" onClick="stop()">Stop</button>
<button class="reset" onClick="reset()">Reset</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put count-up instead id=timer

```js
var clicked = false;
var sec = 00;
var min = 00;

function startClock() {
  if (clicked === false) {
    clock = setInterval("stopWatch()", 1000);
    clicked = true;
  } else if (clicked === true) {}
}

function stopWatch() {
  sec++;
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = sec;
}

function stopClock() {
  window.clearInterval(clock);
  sec = 0;
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = 0;
  clicked = false;
}

var min = 0;
var second = 00;
var zeroPlaceholder = 0;
var counterId = setInterval(function() {
  countUp();
}, 1000);

function countUp() {
  second++;
  if (second == 59) {
    second = 00;
    min = min + 1;
  }
  if (second == 10) {
    zeroPlaceholder = '';
  } else
  if (second == 00) {
    zeroPlaceholder = 0;
  }

  document.getElementById("count-up").innerText = min + ':' + zeroPlaceholder + second;
}
```

```html
<div class="timer">
  <div id="count-up">0:00</div>
  
  <input type="button" id="btnParentButton" value="start timer"  onClick="startClock()"/>
```